# Lossless, graphical audio/video file editor for Mac

Tags: osx, video-editing, audio-editing

I often find myself needing to make simple edits to media files on my Mac. Because this media is saved in lossy formats, I try to avoid re-encoding wherever possible. These edits include:

1. Splitting a media file into smaller, separate clips.
2. Combining multiple clips into one larger file.
3. Removing a segment from the middle of a media file.

Typical formats are mp3 files, aac audio in an m4a container, or h.264 video and aac audio in an mp4 container.

I can currently do **1**, **2**, and **3** with ffmpeg, through some combination of the `concat` video filter and the `-ss` and `-t` parameters. However, editing visual media via a text-based command line is cumbersome and time consuming. Finding the exact timestamp to cut is an exercise in trial and error, and **3** is typically a multi-step process.

Quicktime X is capable of performing **1** without re-encoding, but only on video. And as soon as I attempt **2** or **3**, it insists on re-encoding everything.

Is there a graphical program that will allow me to do **1**, **2**, and **3** on both audio and video files without any re-encoding? Ideally, I would like something with a minimalistic UI to go along with the simple nature of my edits—but at this point, any graphical program will probably be an improvement. I'm not opposed to paying a small amount of money, but anything professionally-priced will be overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of FFMPEG GUI front ends **but** when combining clips you will find that it is necessary to re-encode if any of the following are true:

1. The last frame of one clip is not exactly one frame before a keyframe
2. **Any** of the parameters used for encoding differ between the clips

I would suggest taking a look at [iffmpeg](http://www.iffmpeg.com/) - there is a free trial and the purchase price looks very reasonable. Gives FFMPEG a nice user interface for OS-X.

[image]